# Reusable Javascript for Tab Panels

Tags: javascript, tabs

[image: Multi Use Tab Panels]

[LINK TO IMAGE OF ERRANT BEHAVIOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vovIe.png)(sorry I could not embed a second image)

I have the above two elements that each utilize the same javascript which loads changes the content of the element based on the tab/pill that is chosen.  The content loading is working as expected within the active element, with the correct content for that element.  What is occurring though is that the in-active element goes blank when the active element content changes.(Note the picture is the same but the text is different).

At this time I do purposely have both MAIN tabs with the same item # just until I get this fixed so that is not an error per say, just a workaround to get the in-active content to load up again.

I am not sure how to get the javascript to work completely independent within one element and not affect the other element.

I have a working version posted at jsfiddle located at [Reusable tab script.](https://jsfiddle.net/Jana_S/badzr49m/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chris.tabs ul li.item, #mike.tabs ul li.item').on('click', function() {
    var number = $(this).data('option');
    $('#chris.tabs ul li.item, #mike.tabs ul li.item').removeClass('is-active');
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
    $('#tab_container .container_item').removeClass('is-active');
    $('div[data-item="' + number + '"]').addClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

I know it is involving

```
$('#tab_container .container_item').removeClass('is-active');
$('div[data-item="' + number + '"]').addClass('is-active');
```

I am just not sure how to make these two lines only effect the active element.  I had hoped that by having the element id'd and incorporating earlier in the script was the key.  It helped but not completely.

I have included a picture of the errant behavior above below the default behavior of the tabs image.  This shows the second tab being shown on each element and how the content for the non-active element is emptied while the active element shows it's correct content.

I wish for the non-active element to stay on its default front page, no activity, no change of content, it's not involved (or should not be anyway). 
Again, the working code I am trying to fix is on jsfiddle [JSFiddle of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/Jana_S/badzr49m/3/) which shows exactly the behavior I am trying to describe (if rather poorly).

I would greatly appreciate any inputs

Comment: IMO you've dived to deep into the details on this without first letting us know what it is you are trying to accomplish and what's not working about this. Can you start there, any maybe post a minimal example that demonstrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well what I am trying to accomplish is to have a set of tabs in two separate elements work independently of each other.  These elements are a personal summary about a person.  So one tab is for the main info that is loaded by default, the second tab is their biography and the third tab is a list of their certifications.  I have a working example at the jsfiddle I listed above which is why I didn't take the space here to do so as I thought seeing the working model in full was best.  What's not working is that when a tab is selected in the active element, the element not being used goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to target ids. Those will work better. I tweaked your code in not the neatest of ways to get to understand how it works. But there are easier and cleaner ways to have it done. Try this rough one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab_container').hide();
    $('#main').click(function(){
        $('#bio_info, #certifications_info').hide();
        $('#main').addClass('is-active');
        $('#bio, #certifications').removeClass('is-active');
        $('#main_info').addClass('is-active').show();
        $('#tab_container').show();
     });
     $('#bio').click(function(){
        $('#main_info, #certifications_info').hide();
        $('#bio').addClass('is-active');
        $('#main, #certifications').removeClass('is-active');
        $('#bio_info').addClass('is-active').show();
        $('#tab_container').show();
     });
     $('#certifications').click(function(){
     $('#main_info, #bio_info').hide();
     $('#certifications').addClass('is-active');
     $('#main, #bio').removeClass('is-active');
     $('#certifications_info').addClass('is-active').show();
     $('#tab_container').show();
  });
});
```

The HTML is:

```
 <section id="meet">
 <div class="box">
 <header class="title">
  <h2> Meet The Team</h2>
</header>
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box box-meet">
      <article class="team has-text-centered">
        <tabs id="chris" class="tabs is-toggle is-toggle-rounded is-centered">
          <ul>
            <li class="tab item is-active" id="main" data-option="1"><a><i class="far fa-user-secret" data-fa-transform = "left-6"></i>MAIN</a></li>
            <li class="item" id="bio" data-option="2"> <a><i class="far fa-book" data-fa-transform = "left-6"></i>BIO</a></li>
            <li class="item" id="certifications" data-option="3"><a><i class="far fa-certificate" data-fa-transform = "left-6"></i>CERTIFICATIONS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </tabs>
      </article>
      <div class="box has-text-centered" id="tab_container">
        <div class="container_item is-active" id="main_info" data-item="1">
          <img class="is-round" src="assets/images/chris.jpg">
          <blockquote class="has-text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos impedit alias ipsam ea sit aspernatur facere debitis dicta totam neque labore vel saepe nulla, perspiciatis, sequi eum eaque? Eos, suscipit?
          </blockquote>
          <hr>
          <p class="has-text-left">Christopher Siegle</p>
          <p class="has-text-left">LTC/CHL, Advanced Gun, and Security Trainer</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container_item" id="bio_info" data-item="2">
          <p>BIO BIO BIO BIO BIO</p>
          <H1> BIO BIO BIO BIO</H1>
        </div>
        <div class="container_item" id="certifications_info" data-item="3">
          <p>CERTIFICATIONS</p>
          <H1> CERTIFICATIONS CERTIFICATIONS CERTIFICATIONS</H1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box box-meet">
      <article class="team has-text-centered">
        <tabs id="mike" class="tabs is-toggle is-toggle-rounded is-centered">
          <ul>
            <li class="item is-active" data-option="1"><a><i class="far fa-user-secret" data-fa-transform = "left-6"></i>MAIN</a></li>
            <li class="item" data-option="5"> <a><i class="far fa-book" data-fa-transform = "left-6"></i>BIO</a></li>
            <li class="item" data-option="6"><a><i class="far fa-certificate" data-fa-transform = "left-6"></i>CERTIFICATIONS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </tabs>
      </article>
      <div class="box has-text-centered" id="tab_container">
        <div class="container_item is-active" data-item="1">
          <img class="is-round" src="assets/images/chris.jpg">
          <blockquote class="has-text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos impedit alias ipsam ea sit aspernatur facere debitis dicta totam neque labore vel saepe nulla, perspiciatis, sequi eum eaque? Eos, suscipit?
          </blockquote>
          <hr>
          <p class="has-text-left">Mike Jones</p>
          <p class="has-text-left">Security Trainer</p>

        </div>

        <div class="container_item" data-item="5">
          <p>BIO1 BIO1 BIO1 BIO1 BIO1</p>
          <H1> BIO BIO BIO BIO</H1>
        </div>
        <div class="container_item" data-item="6">
          <p>CERTIFICATIONS1</p>
          <H1> CERTIFICATIONS CERTIFICATIONS CERTIFICATIONS</H1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

`